# How to adjust the height of TabBarView automatically according to the childrens

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using TabBar with Sliver Appbar in Flutter. Tab Bar required a fixed height, But I want that it must increase or decrease its height according to the children, without affecting the working of the SliverAppBar. I tried using NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() but for using NeverScrollableScrollPhysics with the expended widget, but also doesn't work because of SliverAppBar. So how can I fix this issue? Below is my code.

```
    import 'package:fiverrinstructionapp/sample.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AdvancedSliverAppBar extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<AdvancedSliverAppBar> createState() => _AdvancedSliverAppBarState();
}

class _AdvancedSliverAppBarState extends State<AdvancedSliverAppBar> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          delegate: CustomAppBarDelegate(expandedHeight: 250),
          pinned: true,
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 220,
                child: TabBar(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  controller: _tabController,
                  labelColor: Colors.white,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Color(0x50ffffff),
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(bottom: BorderSide.none)),
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(
                        child: Text('Follows',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                fontFamily: "Rany",
                                fontSize: 22))),
                    Tab(
                        child: Text('Discover',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                fontFamily: "Rany",
                                fontSize: 22))),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 1000,
                child: TabBarView(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: [
                    CustomWidget(),
                    Center(
                        child: Text("Discover Tab",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "Rany",
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                color: Color(0xffffffff),
                                fontSize: 20))),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}





class CustomAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final double expandedHeight;

  const CustomAppBarDelegate({
    required this.expandedHeight,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final size = 60;
    final top = expandedHeight - shrinkOffset - size / 2;

    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none, fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        TopVideo(),
        buildAppBar(shrinkOffset),

      ],
    );
  }

  double appear(double shrinkOffset) => shrinkOffset / expandedHeight;

  double disappear(double shrinkOffset) => 1 - shrinkOffset / expandedHeight;

  Widget buildAppBar(double shrinkOffset) => Opacity(
    opacity: appear(shrinkOffset),
    child: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      title: Text("Shawn Mendes", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Rany", fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Color(0xffffffff), fontSize: 20)),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
  );





  @override
  double get maxExtent => expandedHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight + 30;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}


class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
        height: 150,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Card(
          child: Image.network(
            'https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=$index',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      itemCount: 20,
    );
  }
}
```